# Magento 1.7.0.2 mail failure

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am currently getting the following error on my magento logs:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function isPathAllowed() on a non-object in /srv/erg.com/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php on line 476
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I can see the similar issue with possible solution [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/97146/39471)

Please check if this solves your issue.

Comment: I already saw that and that wasn't it unfortunately. I don't have that extension. My mail is failing for some reason.

Comment: Ok , SUPEE-6788 is a Magento patch (its misguiding sometime in that solution when  they say extension, because people starts looking in plugin/extension). So I want to make sure you are not looking on app/* . If so please check if you have auto patch 'enabled' , if so ,in this case patching is done automatically without your info and suddenly some functionality stops working. To check peaches applied/updated https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/64207/39471 . If you have already gone trough please ignore this